# How to open bottomModal sheet from bottom Navigation bar?

Tags: flutter

In my bottom navigation bar I have five icons, four of them opens 4 different screens and I want another one to open **showModalBottomSheet**, but when I implemented it and ran the app it shows error saying

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 2903 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.

I aslo tried using  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) but it also shows error saying **'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.'**
what should i do??

```
class BottomNavigationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavigationPage> createState() => _BottomNavigationPageState();
}

class _BottomNavigationPageState extends State<BottomNavigationPage> {
  int currentIndex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List body = [
      showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const Containers(
              height: 400,
              color: Colors.green,
            );
          }),
      const Containers(
        height: 400,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      const Dashboard(),
      const DepartmentPage(),
      const Dashboard(),
      const DepartmentPage(),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: body[currentIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        //showUnselectedLabels: true,
        selectedItemColor: AppColor.btnColor,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColor.btnColor),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (int newindex) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = newindex;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: '',
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: AppColor.btnColor,
              size: 30,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'होम',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.people,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'शाखा हरु ',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.people,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'सूचना हरु',
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'सूचना हरु',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `Containers`? Is it a custom widget or you meant `Container`?

Comment: @ruleboy21 it's a custom widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add the `showModalBottomSheet` to the `body` list. You can check if `newindex == 0` when a `BottomNavigationBarItem` is tapped and then show it. Try this

```
class BottomNavigationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavigationPage> createState() => _BottomNavigationPageState();
}

class _BottomNavigationPageState extends State<BottomNavigationPage> {
  int currentIndex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List body = [
      const Containers(
        height: 400,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      const Dashboard(),
      const DepartmentPage(),
      const Dashboard(),
      const DepartmentPage(),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: body[currentIndex-1],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        //showUnselectedLabels: true,
        selectedItemColor: AppColor.btnColor,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColor.btnColor),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (int newindex) {
          if (newindex == 0) {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return const Containers(
                  height: 400,
                  color: Colors.green,
                );
              }
            );
          } else {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = newindex;
            });
          }
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: '',
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: AppColor.btnColor,
              size: 30,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'होम',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.people,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'शाखा हरु ',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.people,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'सूचना हरु',
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'सूचना हरु',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.task,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```